# How to prove that this recurrent sequence is Cauchy

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:(E,d)\to (E,d)$  such that $$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y), \forall x,y\in E ,x\neq y$$ where $E$ is compact

I want to prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point

I consider the recurrent sequence $$\begin{cases} x_{n+1}=f^{n+1}(x_0)\\ x_0\in E\end{cases}$$

But how to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence?

if $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ and $x_{n+1}=f^{n+1}(x_0)$ if for example i want to to see $\lim_{n\to+\infty} d(x_n,x_{n+1})$

$d(x_n,x_{n+1})= d(f(x_{n-1}),f(x_n))<d(x_{n-1},x_n)<...<d(x_0,x_1)$ then the limit is not 0
how to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence ?

Comment: Do you know already this is true? I would say it might not be true

Comment: Try writing $d(f(x), f(y)) \leq rd(x,y)$ for some $r < 1$. Then $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) \leq r^n d(x_0, x_1) \leq r^n \operatorname{diam}(E)$ lets you argue that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: You don't need to prove it's Cauchy. By compactness, $x_n$ will have a convergent subsequence, and you can use the stated property to show that the limit of that subsequence is a fixed point of the sequence.

Comment: Oh I see, it's compact...

Comment: @Neal Your $r$ doesn't have to be constant for all $x$ and $y$

Comment: Take the sup over all pairs. This is strictly less than $1$ by compactness.

Comment: @Neal Take $E=[0,1]$ with standard metric, and $f(x)=\sin{x}$. Then $r=1$.

Comment: You cannot have $d(f(x),f(x))<d(x,y)$ for all $x,y$, but only for $x\ne y$.

Comment: @Neal But only because the OP accidentally postulated $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ also for $x=y$, which is contradictory anyway. With the correct caveat, your argument takes the sup over $E^2$minus its diagonal, a non-compact space

Comment: @RobArthan if $x_{n+1}$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{\varphi(n)}$ converge to x is it the same convegent subsequence for $x_n$ ? after that is it sufficient to do this for a subsequence and say that the limit of the sub sequence is the fixed point?

Answer (score 2):

The continuous map $g\colon E\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto d(x,f(x))$ assumes its minimum at some point $\hat x$. Assume $\hat x\ne f(\hat x)$. Then $g(f(\hat x))=d(f(\hat x),f(f(\hat x))<d(\hat x,f(\hat x))=g(\hat x)$, contradiction.
We conclude that $\hat x$ is a fixpoint.

Now that we have a fixpoint, it also follows that the recurrence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ converges to $\hat x$ (nd of course uniqueness of the fixpoint): On the compact set $\overline{\{\,x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}}$, the continuos function $d(\cdot,\hat x)$ assumes its minimum at some point $y$. As also $f(y)$ is in that closure, it follows $d(f(y),\hat x)\ge d(y,\hat x)$, which contradicts the given inequality unless $y=\hat x$. Hence there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}\to y=\hat x$, which implies $x_n\to x$ because $d(x_n,\hat x)$ is decreasing.

Comment: Ahhh right thank you is this give me the unicity or i must prove it by contradiction ?

Comment: @PolineSandra This gives you existence of a fixpoint. Uniqueness is clear from $d(x,y9=d(f(x),f(y))$ when $x,y$ are fixpoints.

Comment: Please i don't understand your second method can you explain me more how to do without using the first method ?

Comment: why $f(y)$ is in your set? and where is used the compactness of $E$ ?